# Mustache JS and singular/plural

Tags: mustache

I use mustache for templating my javascript ajax calls, Here is my data and the template:

```
{'joined':1} // ajax responde data json.

var myTemplate = '{{ joined }} person joined so far.'
```

It works, however I want to fix the grammer in this, if more than 1 person joins, I want to show `5 people joined so far`.

How to achieve this without manipulating the server side ajax json responder ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add conditional logic inside the JavaScript object, if you can coax your server-side AJAX into delivering it that way:

```
var json = {
    'joined': 1,
    'ppl': function() {
        return (this.joined === 1) ? 'person' : 'people'
    }
} // ajax responde data json.
var myTemplate = '{{ joined }} {{ppl}} joined so far.'

Mustache.to_html(myTemplate, json);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/H8tqn/

Comment: I gather from this being the accepted answer that there isn't any way to do this in mustache itself, right? It handles true-false vars as conditionals, no other comparisons?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do it with only Mustache, but for the case your JSON contains not only a number, but an array of values, together with the size of the array:

```
var json = {
  'rows': ['a','b','c'],
  'numRows': function() {
      return this.rows.length
   }
} // ajax response data json.
```

In order to do it, you can use one of the following Mustache templates:

In the simple case, when you just need to add "s" for plural:

```
var myTemplate = '{{ numRows }} link{{^rows}}s{{/rows}}{{#rows.1}}s{{/rows.1}} parsed so far.'
```

---

The result:

```
0 links parsed so far.
1 link parsed so far.
2 links parsed so far.
```

In the general case, when the plural is special (like people/person):

```
var myTemplate2 = '{{ numRows }} {{^rows}}people{{/rows}}{{#rows.0}}{{^rows.1}}person{{/rows.1}}{{/rows.0}}{{#rows.1}}people{{/rows.1}} joined so far.'
```

---

The result:

```
0 people joined so far.
1 person joined so far.
2 people joined so far.
```

You can find both templates applied in practice here:
http://jsfiddle.net/H8tqn/9/

---

P.S. I will post again here if I can find the solution for this one:

```
No people joined so far.
1 person joined so far.
2 people joined so far.
```

Comment: You are mentioning json, but you are referring to a Javascript object. Json can't contain functions.